# Why is the graph of a quadratic $y=x^2$ a parabola?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, conic-sections

I had this question and saw the other thread, and the proof of why all quadratics were parabolas started with the axiom that $y = x^2$ is a parabola.

I don't really understand why $y = x^2$ is a parabola

I get that if you plot it you get a parabola, but why is that the case?

I didn't know about the multiple definitions of a parabola, I haven't yet learned about that I am in highschool.

I don't really know what to say, I am just gonna go with the definition from the other thread: the parabola is the curve that is equidistant from a point (focus) and a line that is perpendicular to the axis of the parabola.

link to other thread: [Why is the graph of a quadratic function a parabola?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684216/why-is-the-graph-of-a-quadratic-function-a-parabola)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, Arsh Dixit. There are several (equivalent) definitions of a parabola. We can't answer your question if you don't tell us which one you have in mind.

Comment: @Joe Oh, sorry I didn't know about that, I haven't yet learned about that I am in highschool.



--- </hr>

I don't really know what to say, I am just gonna go with the definition from the other thread: the parabola is the curve that is equidistant from a point (Focus) and a line that is perpendicular to the axis of the parabola.

Comment: In this case, you can include your definition in the question body. Also, please include the link for the other thread,

Comment: See if [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1148999/888233) answers your question.

Comment: Wikipedia answers your question here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Axis_of_symmetry_parallel_to_the_y_axis

Comment: @soupless edits done, do give me a few to look at the links I am in the middle of something

Comment: @ArshDixit: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Each point on the parabola $y=x^2$ is equidistant from the focus $(0,1/4)$, and the directrix $y=-1/4$. You can prove this by considering a general point $(x,x^2)$ that lies on the parabola, and computing the respective distances.

Comment: What @Joe said is also done here. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684245/819784 Take a look, Arsh.

Comment: Hello, I really really appreciate the answers, I tried looking through them I couldn't understand it, it's 3 am and very sleep deprived, barely have a grip on reality, gonna go for a snooze and try tomorrow